# When disabling GL_DEPTH_TEST, textures disappear

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

Okay so I have this fully working scene, where there is a vinyl player on a shelf with speakers. Everything works (models and textures using [GLM](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/), interface using Mac-Cocoa).

What I am implementing now is a "dock-like" bar where there are floating album covers so you can pick one to play. It currently works great, but if you zoom in too further they get behind other objects and disappear.

What I first tried: glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST). But when I do this, all the textures from my album covers, which are 3D models as well, go grey.

The depth problem is fixed as intended, but the problem here is with the textures. I am using this version of GLM model loader: http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/ which loads the textures automatically.

GL_DEPTH_TEST enabled:
[image: GL_DEPTH_TEST enabled]

GL_DEPTH_TEST disabled:
[image: GL_DEPTH_TEST disabled]

Any ideas?

Comment: I notice that only the albums went untextured. The record player and wall still look textured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without access to your code and assets it's just a guess, but it looks like your model for the album covers has both front and back faces.  With `GL_DEPTH_TEST` disabled, the back face is being drawn after the front face, and since the depth test is being skipped, it covers up the front face.

Try turning on backface culling if you haven't already:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Comment: Thank you. The back face culling was indeed the problem. But another thing was also causing problems: I was using triangulated models for the albums. So it would only show triangular parts of each face. Anyway, I re-exported the models without triangulating and it worked!